# How to retrieve Google Fit Step data from server?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit

I have recently started playing around with the GoogleFit APIs.  I have gone through several stackoverflow posts about this problem but have not seen a good answer yet that works for me.  Most answers point to outdated API.

The task I want to accomplish is simple:
Read the daily step count from the **server**.

Ideally I want the step count retrieved to match what is displayed on https://fit.google.com/ but I have not been able to do so.

Here is my set up:

**Request access**:

```
  val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                    .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                    .build()

            if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Already Has permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {

                GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                        this, // your activity
                        FIT_REQUEST_CODE,
                        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                        fitnessOptions)
            }
```

To my understanding the method below should reach out to the server and retrieve the step count. 
According to the documentation there is  `readDailyTotalFromLocalDevice(...)` method so if I wanted to get the data from the device I would just use that method. But both of these methods seem to return the same exact values.

**Query Data**

```
Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    tvResult.text = "Steps: ${it.dataPoints[0].getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS)}"
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    tvResult.text = "Error"
                }
```

For context: the step count (at the time of writing this) on https://fit.google.com is **6000** and the value I am getting back from the method above is **4** Furthermore I do not see any traffic being generated on the GoogleAPI console for fitness api which confirms the hypothesis that the request is never going out to the server.

What I have tried (without success):

- Manually constructing the request and explicitly adding enable server
  query
- Adding subscription for the same data type that I am trying to read

**How can I read the daily step count data that is stored on the cloud fitness data store?**

Comment: `readDailyTotal` should also take in the client as a parameter, no? I guess it's not giving you any compile errors. but I don't see a signature in the doc that only takes in the DataType.

Comment: It is available under [history client](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient.html#readDailyTotal(com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType))